# How to extract weights "from input layer to hidden layer" and "from hidden layer to output layer" with Keras API?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am new to Keras and I am trying to get the weights in Keras. I know how to do it in Tensorflow in Python.

Code:

```
data = np.array(attributes, 'int64')
target = np.array(labels, 'int64')

feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=2, dtype=tf.float32)]
learningRate = 0.1
epoch = 10000

# https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics
validation_metrics = {
"accuracy": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
"precision": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
"recall": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
"mean_absolute_error": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_absolute_error ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
"false_negatives": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_false_negatives ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
"false_positives": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_false_positives ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
"true_positives": tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_true_positives ,
prediction_key = tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES)
}

# validation monitor
validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(data, target, every_n_steps=500,
metrics = validation_metrics)

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
feature_columns = feature_columns,
hidden_units = [3],
activation_fn = tf.nn.sigmoid,
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learningRate),
model_dir = "model",
config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs = 1)
)

classifier.fit(data, target, steps = epoch,
monitors = [validation_monitor])

# print('Params:', classifier.get_variable_names())
'''
Params: ['dnn/binary_logistic_head/dnn/learning_rate', 'dnn/hiddenlayer_0/biases', 'dnn/hiddenlayer_0/weights', 'dnn/logits/biases', 'dnn/logits/weights', 'global_step']
'''

print('total steps:', classifier.get_variable_value("global_step"))
print('weight from input layer to hidden layer: ', classifier.get_variable_value("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/weights"))
print('weight from hidden layer to output layer: ', classifier.get_variable_value("dnn/logits/weights"))
```

Is there any way to obtain the weights in Keras like in Tensorflow:

1. The weights from input layer to hidden layer
2. The weights from hidden layer to output layer

This is my model in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer lies directly in the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/).

Comment: @desertnaut it's okay mate I appreciate that. Sorry if my question is not good enough for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access and set the weights or parameters of the model's layers using `get_weights` and `set_weights` methods. From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/):

> `layer.get_weights()`: returns the weights of the layer as a list of
>   Numpy arrays. `layer.set_weights(weights)`: sets the weights of the
>   layer from a list of Numpy arrays (with the same shapes as the output
>   of `get_weights`).

Each Keras model has a `layers` attribute which is the list of all the layers in the model. For example, in the sample model you provided, you can get the weights of the first `Dense` layer by running:

```
model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

It would return a list of two numpy arrays: the first one is the kernel parameters of the Dense layer the second array is the bias parameters.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. But how do I get the weight of the Last Layer?
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')).

Comment: @sekti92uk Just use the index of the layer on `layers` list. The last layer is the fourth layer in the model, so its index would be 3; therefore: `model.layers[3].get_weights()`. Alternatively, you can write: `model.layers[-1].get_weights()` since it is the last layer as well.